# Qt C++: Save project in file

Tags: c++, file, qt, save, project

I would like to save data from memory to some file. This includes QFileSystemModel and others which are important for program to create some progress. How to create some export file from where those settings would be read and how to read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create some schema for storing all the important persistent variables for your class/file.

Make a save function that pushes all these variables out to a file.

Make a load function that retrieves all these variables from a file.

If your file has a lot of binary data or a large structure you probably should make your own.

Qt has XML and JSON available if one of those make sense to use.  (Tree's or node based information).

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-xml.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/xmlpatterns-filetree.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/json.html

If they are a few settings variables, that are short, such as a string or two, or native Qt objects, like a `QRect`, a `QPoint`, a `QStringList`, etc, you can do it with `QSettings`.

Also `QSettings` has a really nifty way of handling defaults, and fall-backs, and using the application name and the organization name.  I like the INI-format.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html

Hope that helps.